# Windows Sandbox fails to connect, Error 0x80072746

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, hyper-v, sandbox, windows-sandbox

Windows Sandbox has stopped working recently, despite no changes to the system or software. When launched from the Start Menu, it shows the Windows Sandbox splash screen (blue sandbox icon on a gray background) for several minutes, then it shows Windows Sandbox window (as in, a window frame with the title bar at the top) but it's totally black and unresponsive inside. After a few more minutes, it crashes and one of two error message boxes appear:

> ```
> Windows Sandbox failed to connect.
>
> Error 0x80072746. The connection to 
> the sandbox was lost.
> An existing connection was forcibly 
> closed by the remote host.
> ```

> ```
> Windows Sandbox failed to connect.
>
> Error 0x800705b4. This operation
> returned because the timeout period 
> expired.
> ```

It is worth noting that the line "The connection to the sandbox was lost" is what would normally appear in a similar messagebox when I would manually close a Windows Sandbox instance (back when it was working properly on my device).

After closing the error message box, "WindowsSandbox.exe" remains running in Task Manager. It must be manually terminated before trying to launch Sandbox again.

Windows Sandbox was working fine until a few days ago, and as mentioned, nothing has changed recently about my computer. Windows Update has not had any new updates since well before this problem arose. I have run `sfc /scannow` and `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` but both found no issues. I have launched "Turn Windows features on or off" (OptionalFeatures.exe) and have tried disabling Hyper-V and Windows Sandbox, rebooting, re-enabling them, and rebooting again, with no effect. I have confirmed that virtualization is enabled in BIOS.

EDIT: Below are the Event Viewer logs of a Windows Sandbox attempted launch. I've copied and pasted the general description from each event for readability's sake, but the full XML is below that.

```
The operation 'Create' succeeded on nic C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB444 (Friendly Name: Default Switch), Instance Id {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}.
-
NIC C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB444 (Friendly Name: Default Switch) successfully connected to port C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB444 (Friendly Name: Default Switch) on switch C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB444(Friendly Name: Default Switch).
-
Switch C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB444 (Friendly Name: Default Switch) successfully initialized.
-
Port C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB445 (Friendly Name: Host Vnic C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB444) successfully created on switch C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB444 (Friendly Name: Default Switch).
-
The operation 'Create' succeeded on nic C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB445 (Friendly Name: Default Switch), Instance Id {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}.
-
Miniport NIC C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB445 (Friendly Name: Default Switch) successfully initialized.
-
NIC C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB445 (Friendly Name: Default Switch) successfully connected to port C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB445 (Friendly Name: Host Vnic C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB444) on switch C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB444(Friendly Name: Default Switch).
-
The operation 'Create' succeeded on nic 377C86D7-E419-4E14-A730-C31123C25371--25F8AEFE-F31E-47BF-8882-672BB0AACF8E (Friendly Name: ), Instance Id {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}.
-
NIC 377C86D7-E419-4E14-A730-C31123C25371--25F8AEFE-F31E-47BF-8882-672BB0AACF8E (Friendly Name: ) successfully connected to port 25F8AEFE-F31E-47BF-8882-672BB0AACF8E (Friendly Name: 25F8AEFE-F31E-47BF-8882-672BB0AACF8E) on switch C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB444(Friendly Name: Default Switch).
-
NIC 377C86D7-E419-4E14-A730-C31123C25371--25F8AEFE-F31E-47BF-8882-672BB0AACF8E successfully disconnected from port .
-
NIC 377C86D7-E419-4E14-A730-C31123C25371--25F8AEFE-F31E-47BF-8882-672BB0AACF8E (Friendly Name: ) successfully connected to port 25F8AEFE-F31E-47BF-8882-672BB0AACF8E (Friendly Name: 25F8AEFE-F31E-47BF-8882-672BB0AACF8E) on switch C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB444(Friendly Name: Default Switch).
-
Networking driver in 377c86d7-e419-4e14-a730-c31123c25371 is loaded and the protocol version is negotiated to the most recent version (Virtual machine ID 377C86D7-E419-4E14-A730-C31123C25371).
-
Virtual Disk: Service stopped.
-
NIC 377C86D7-E419-4E14-A730-C31123C25371--25F8AEFE-F31E-47BF-8882-672BB0AACF8E successfully disconnected from port .
```

XML export:

```
<Events>
  <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
      <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VmSwitch" Guid="{67dc0d66-3695-47c0-9642-33f76f7bd7ad}"/>
      <EventID>233</EventID>
      <Version>0</Version>
      <Level>4</Level>
      <Task>0</Task>
      <Opcode>0</Opcode>
      <Keywords>0x8000000000000080</Keywords>
      <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-01-01T01:59:13.1314069Z"/>
      <EventRecordID>13410</EventRecordID>
      <Correlation/>
      <Execution ProcessID="9584" ThreadID="23840"/>
      <Channel>System</Channel>
      <Computer>Legion</Computer>
      <Security UserID="S-1-5-83-1-930907863-1309991961-298004647-1901314595"/>
    </System>
    <EventData>
      <Data Name="NicNameLen">74</Data>
      <Data Name="NicName">377C86D7-E419-4E14-A730-C31123C25371--25F8AEFE-F31E-47BF-8882-672BB0AACF8E</Data>
      <Data Name="NicFNameLen">0</Data>
      <Data Name="NicFName"/>
      <Data Name="Operation">8</Data>
      <Data Name="NicInstanceId">{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}</Data>
    </EventData>
  </Event>
  <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
      <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VmSwitch" Guid="{67dc0d66-3695-47c0-9642-33f76f7bd7ad}"/>
      <EventID>234</EventID>
      <Version>0</Version>
      <Level>4</Level>
      <Task>0</Task>
      <Opcode>0</Opcode>
      <Keywords>0x8000000000000080</Keywords>
      <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-01-01T01:59:13.1181486Z"/>
      <EventRecordID>13409</EventRecordID>
      <Correlation/>
      <Execution ProcessID="9584" ThreadID="23840"/>
      <Channel>System</Channel>
      <Computer>Legion</Computer>
      <Security UserID="S-1-5-83-1-930907863-1309991961-298004647-1901314595"/>
    </System>
    <EventData>
      <Data Name="NicNameLen">74</Data>
      <Data Name="NicName">377C86D7-E419-4E14-A730-C31123C25371--25F8AEFE-F31E-47BF-8882-672BB0AACF8E</Data>
      <Data Name="PortNameLen">1</Data>
      <Data Name="PortName"/>
    </EventData>
  </Event>
  <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
      <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VmSwitch" Guid="{67dc0d66-3695-47c0-9642-33f76f7bd7ad}"/>
      <EventID>234</EventID>
      <Version>0</Version>
      <Level>4</Level>
      <Task>0</Task>
      <Opcode>0</Opcode>
      <Keywords>0x8000000000000080</Keywords>
      <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-01-01T01:59:13.1152001Z"/>
      <EventRecordID>13408</EventRecordID>
      <Correlation/>
      <Execution ProcessID="6324" ThreadID="10656"/>
      <Channel>System</Channel>
      <Computer>Legion</Computer>
      <Security UserID="S-1-5-18"/>
    </System>
    <EventData>
      <Data Name="NicNameLen">74</Data>
      <Data Name="NicName">377C86D7-E419-4E14-A730-C31123C25371--25F8AEFE-F31E-47BF-8882-672BB0AACF8E</Data>
      <Data Name="PortNameLen">1</Data>
      <Data Name="PortName"/>
    </EventData>
  </Event>
  <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
      <Provider Name="Virtual Disk Service"/>
      <EventID Qualifiers="16896">4</EventID>
      <Version>0</Version>
      <Level>4</Level>
      <Task>0</Task>
      <Opcode>0</Opcode>
      <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
      <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-01-01T01:54:31.6708484Z"/>
      <EventRecordID>13407</EventRecordID>
      <Correlation/>
      <Execution ProcessID="6136" ThreadID="0"/>
      <Channel>System</Channel>
      <Computer>Legion</Computer>
      <Security/>
    </System>
    <EventData>
      <Data>@2010001</Data>
    </EventData>
  </Event>
  <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
      <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VmSwitch" Guid="{67dc0d66-3695-47c0-9642-33f76f7bd7ad}"/>
      <EventID>102</EventID>
      <Version>0</Version>
      <Level>4</Level>
      <Task>1019</Task>
      <Opcode>0</Opcode>
      <Keywords>0x8000000000000080</Keywords>
      <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-01-01T01:46:59.0580814Z"/>
      <EventRecordID>13405</EventRecordID>
      <Correlation/>
      <Execution ProcessID="844" ThreadID="16024"/>
      <Channel>System</Channel>
      <Computer>Legion</Computer>
      <Security UserID="S-1-5-83-1-930907863-1309991961-298004647-1901314595"/>
    </System>
    <EventData>
      <Data Name="VMNameLen">36</Data>
      <Data Name="VMName">377c86d7-e419-4e14-a730-c31123c25371</Data>
      <Data Name="VMIdLen">36</Data>
      <Data Name="VMId">377C86D7-E419-4E14-A730-C31123C25371</Data>
    </EventData>
  </Event>
  <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
      <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VmSwitch" Guid="{67dc0d66-3695-47c0-9642-33f76f7bd7ad}"/>
      <EventID>232</EventID>
      <Version>0</Version>
      <Level>4</Level>
      <Task>0</Task>
      <Opcode>0</Opcode>
      <Keywords>0x8000000000000080</Keywords>
      <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-01-01T01:46:50.4183945Z"/>
      <EventRecordID>13404</EventRecordID>
      <Correlation/>
      <Execution ProcessID="6324" ThreadID="10656"/>
      <Channel>System</Channel>
      <Computer>Legion</Computer>
      <Security UserID="S-1-5-18"/>
    </System>
    <EventData>
      <Data Name="NicNameLen">74</Data>
      <Data Name="NicName">377C86D7-E419-4E14-A730-C31123C25371--25F8AEFE-F31E-47BF-8882-672BB0AACF8E</Data>
      <Data Name="NicFNameLen">0</Data>
      <Data Name="NicFName"/>
      <Data Name="PortNameLen">36</Data>
      <Data Name="PortName">25F8AEFE-F31E-47BF-8882-672BB0AACF8E</Data>
      <Data Name="PortFNameLen">36</Data>
      <Data Name="PortFName">25F8AEFE-F31E-47BF-8882-672BB0AACF8E</Data>
      <Data Name="SwitchNameLen">36</Data>
      <Data Name="SwitchName">C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB444</Data>
      <Data Name="SwitchFNameLen">14</Data>
      <Data Name="SwitchFName">Default Switch</Data>
    </EventData>
  </Event>
  <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
      <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VmSwitch" Guid="{67dc0d66-3695-47c0-9642-33f76f7bd7ad}"/>
      <EventID>234</EventID>
      <Version>0</Version>
      <Level>4</Level>
      <Task>0</Task>
      <Opcode>0</Opcode>
      <Keywords>0x8000000000000080</Keywords>
      <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-01-01T01:46:50.4122751Z"/>
      <EventRecordID>13403</EventRecordID>
      <Correlation/>
      <Execution ProcessID="6324" ThreadID="10656"/>
      <Channel>System</Channel>
      <Computer>Legion</Computer>
      <Security UserID="S-1-5-18"/>
    </System>
    <EventData>
      <Data Name="NicNameLen">74</Data>
      <Data Name="NicName">377C86D7-E419-4E14-A730-C31123C25371--25F8AEFE-F31E-47BF-8882-672BB0AACF8E</Data>
      <Data Name="PortNameLen">1</Data>
      <Data Name="PortName"/>
    </EventData>
  </Event>
  <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
      <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VmSwitch" Guid="{67dc0d66-3695-47c0-9642-33f76f7bd7ad}"/>
      <EventID>232</EventID>
      <Version>0</Version>
      <Level>4</Level>
      <Task>0</Task>
      <Opcode>0</Opcode>
      <Keywords>0x8000000000000080</Keywords>
      <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-01-01T01:46:39.8290588Z"/>
      <EventRecordID>13402</EventRecordID>
      <Correlation/>
      <Execution ProcessID="9584" ThreadID="10016"/>
      <Channel>System</Channel>
      <Computer>Legion</Computer>
      <Security UserID="S-1-5-83-1-930907863-1309991961-298004647-1901314595"/>
    </System>
    <EventData>
      <Data Name="NicNameLen">74</Data>
      <Data Name="NicName">377C86D7-E419-4E14-A730-C31123C25371--25F8AEFE-F31E-47BF-8882-672BB0AACF8E</Data>
      <Data Name="NicFNameLen">0</Data>
      <Data Name="NicFName"/>
      <Data Name="PortNameLen">36</Data>
      <Data Name="PortName">25F8AEFE-F31E-47BF-8882-672BB0AACF8E</Data>
      <Data Name="PortFNameLen">36</Data>
      <Data Name="PortFName">25F8AEFE-F31E-47BF-8882-672BB0AACF8E</Data>
      <Data Name="SwitchNameLen">36</Data>
      <Data Name="SwitchName">C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB444</Data>
      <Data Name="SwitchFNameLen">14</Data>
      <Data Name="SwitchFName">Default Switch</Data>
    </EventData>
  </Event>
  <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
      <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VmSwitch" Guid="{67dc0d66-3695-47c0-9642-33f76f7bd7ad}"/>
      <EventID>233</EventID>
      <Version>0</Version>
      <Level>4</Level>
      <Task>0</Task>
      <Opcode>0</Opcode>
      <Keywords>0x8000000000000080</Keywords>
      <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-01-01T01:46:39.7599988Z"/>
      <EventRecordID>13401</EventRecordID>
      <Correlation/>
      <Execution ProcessID="9584" ThreadID="10016"/>
      <Channel>System</Channel>
      <Computer>Legion</Computer>
      <Security UserID="S-1-5-83-1-930907863-1309991961-298004647-1901314595"/>
    </System>
    <EventData>
      <Data Name="NicNameLen">74</Data>
      <Data Name="NicName">377C86D7-E419-4E14-A730-C31123C25371--25F8AEFE-F31E-47BF-8882-672BB0AACF8E</Data>
      <Data Name="NicFNameLen">1</Data>
      <Data Name="NicFName"/>
      <Data Name="Operation">7</Data>
      <Data Name="NicInstanceId">{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}</Data>
    </EventData>
  </Event>
  <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
      <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VmSwitch" Guid="{67dc0d66-3695-47c0-9642-33f76f7bd7ad}"/>
      <EventID>232</EventID>
      <Version>0</Version>
      <Level>4</Level>
      <Task>0</Task>
      <Opcode>0</Opcode>
      <Keywords>0x8000000000000080</Keywords>
      <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-01-01T01:46:33.2991714Z"/>
      <EventRecordID>13400</EventRecordID>
      <Correlation/>
      <Execution ProcessID="6324" ThreadID="10656"/>
      <Channel>System</Channel>
      <Computer>Legion</Computer>
      <Security UserID="S-1-5-18"/>
    </System>
    <EventData>
      <Data Name="NicNameLen">36</Data>
      <Data Name="NicName">C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB445</Data>
      <Data Name="NicFNameLen">14</Data>
      <Data Name="NicFName">Default Switch</Data>
      <Data Name="PortNameLen">36</Data>
      <Data Name="PortName">C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB445</Data>
      <Data Name="PortFNameLen">46</Data>
      <Data Name="PortFName">Host Vnic C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB444</Data>
      <Data Name="SwitchNameLen">36</Data>
      <Data Name="SwitchName">C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB444</Data>
      <Data Name="SwitchFNameLen">14</Data>
      <Data Name="SwitchFName">Default Switch</Data>
    </EventData>
  </Event>
  <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
      <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VmSwitch" Guid="{67dc0d66-3695-47c0-9642-33f76f7bd7ad}"/>
      <EventID>7</EventID>
      <Version>0</Version>
      <Level>4</Level>
      <Task>1004</Task>
      <Opcode>0</Opcode>
      <Keywords>0x8000000000000080</Keywords>
      <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-01-01T01:46:18.8856115Z"/>
      <EventRecordID>13399</EventRecordID>
      <Correlation/>
      <Execution ProcessID="6324" ThreadID="10656"/>
      <Channel>System</Channel>
      <Computer>Legion</Computer>
      <Security UserID="S-1-5-18"/>
    </System>
    <EventData>
      <Data Name="NicNameLen">36</Data>
      <Data Name="NicName">C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB445</Data>
      <Data Name="NicFNameLen">14</Data>
      <Data Name="NicFName">Default Switch</Data>
    </EventData>
  </Event>
  <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
      <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VmSwitch" Guid="{67dc0d66-3695-47c0-9642-33f76f7bd7ad}"/>
      <EventID>233</EventID>
      <Version>0</Version>
      <Level>4</Level>
      <Task>0</Task>
      <Opcode>0</Opcode>
      <Keywords>0x8000000000000080</Keywords>
      <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-01-01T01:46:18.7872832Z"/>
      <EventRecordID>13398</EventRecordID>
      <Correlation/>
      <Execution ProcessID="6324" ThreadID="10656"/>
      <Channel>System</Channel>
      <Computer>Legion</Computer>
      <Security UserID="S-1-5-18"/>
    </System>
    <EventData>
      <Data Name="NicNameLen">36</Data>
      <Data Name="NicName">C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB445</Data>
      <Data Name="NicFNameLen">14</Data>
      <Data Name="NicFName">Default Switch</Data>
      <Data Name="Operation">7</Data>
      <Data Name="NicInstanceId">{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}</Data>
    </EventData>
  </Event>
  <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
      <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VmSwitch" Guid="{67dc0d66-3695-47c0-9642-33f76f7bd7ad}"/>
      <EventID>264</EventID>
      <Version>0</Version>
      <Level>4</Level>
      <Task>0</Task>
      <Opcode>0</Opcode>
      <Keywords>0x8000000000000080</Keywords>
      <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-01-01T01:46:18.3158596Z"/>
      <EventRecordID>13397</EventRecordID>
      <Correlation/>
      <Execution ProcessID="6324" ThreadID="10656"/>
      <Channel>System</Channel>
      <Computer>Legion</Computer>
      <Security UserID="S-1-5-18"/>
    </System>
    <EventData>
      <Data Name="PortNameLen">36</Data>
      <Data Name="PortName">C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB445</Data>
      <Data Name="PortFNameLen">46</Data>
      <Data Name="PortFName">Host Vnic C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB444</Data>
      <Data Name="SwitchNameLen">36</Data>
      <Data Name="SwitchName">C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB444</Data>
      <Data Name="SwitchFNameLen">14</Data>
      <Data Name="SwitchFName">Default Switch</Data>
      <Data Name="Flags">1</Data>
      <Data Name="OwnerService">1</Data>
    </EventData>
  </Event>
  <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
      <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VmSwitch" Guid="{67dc0d66-3695-47c0-9642-33f76f7bd7ad}"/>
      <EventID>9</EventID>
      <Version>0</Version>
      <Level>4</Level>
      <Task>1005</Task>
      <Opcode>0</Opcode>
      <Keywords>0x8000000000000080</Keywords>
      <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-01-01T01:46:17.4911895Z"/>
      <EventRecordID>13396</EventRecordID>
      <Correlation/>
      <Execution ProcessID="6324" ThreadID="10656"/>
      <Channel>System</Channel>
      <Computer>Legion</Computer>
      <Security UserID="S-1-5-18"/>
    </System>
    <EventData>
      <Data Name="SwitchNameLen">36</Data>
      <Data Name="SwitchName">C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB444</Data>
      <Data Name="SwitchFNameLen">14</Data>
      <Data Name="SwitchFName">Default Switch</Data>
      <Data Name="Flags">32</Data>
      <Data Name="OwnerService">1</Data>
    </EventData>
  </Event>
  <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
      <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VmSwitch" Guid="{67dc0d66-3695-47c0-9642-33f76f7bd7ad}"/>
      <EventID>232</EventID>
      <Version>0</Version>
      <Level>4</Level>
      <Task>0</Task>
      <Opcode>0</Opcode>
      <Keywords>0x8000000000000080</Keywords>
      <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-01-01T01:46:17.4909333Z"/>
      <EventRecordID>13395</EventRecordID>
      <Correlation/>
      <Execution ProcessID="6324" ThreadID="10656"/>
      <Channel>System</Channel>
      <Computer>Legion</Computer>
      <Security UserID="S-1-5-18"/>
    </System>
    <EventData>
      <Data Name="NicNameLen">36</Data>
      <Data Name="NicName">C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB444</Data>
      <Data Name="NicFNameLen">14</Data>
      <Data Name="NicFName">Default Switch</Data>
      <Data Name="PortNameLen">36</Data>
      <Data Name="PortName">C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB444</Data>
      <Data Name="PortFNameLen">14</Data>
      <Data Name="PortFName">Default Switch</Data>
      <Data Name="SwitchNameLen">36</Data>
      <Data Name="SwitchName">C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB444</Data>
      <Data Name="SwitchFNameLen">14</Data>
      <Data Name="SwitchFName">Default Switch</Data>
    </EventData>
  </Event>
  <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
      <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VmSwitch" Guid="{67dc0d66-3695-47c0-9642-33f76f7bd7ad}"/>
      <EventID>233</EventID>
      <Version>0</Version>
      <Level>4</Level>
      <Task>0</Task>
      <Opcode>0</Opcode>
      <Keywords>0x8000000000000080</Keywords>
      <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-01-01T01:46:17.4908039Z"/>
      <EventRecordID>13394</EventRecordID>
      <Correlation/>
      <Execution ProcessID="6324" ThreadID="10656"/>
      <Channel>System</Channel>
      <Computer>Legion</Computer>
      <Security UserID="S-1-5-18"/>
    </System>
    <EventData>
      <Data Name="NicNameLen">36</Data>
      <Data Name="NicName">C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB444</Data>
      <Data Name="NicFNameLen">14</Data>
      <Data Name="NicFName">Default Switch</Data>
      <Data Name="Operation">7</Data>
      <Data Name="NicInstanceId">{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}</Data>
    </EventData>
  </Event>
</Events>
```

As you can see, there are no error events. According to the event log, it seems like it's working fine... until it doesn't. (note that the 2nd-to-last event, "Service stopped," happened a few minutes *after* I got the Error 0x80072746 popup. Soon after, it showed the Error 0x800705b4 popup, so I think these two events correspond to WindowsSandbox.exe timing out from inactivity after the main failure already occurred. In other words, I think these last two events are the result, not the cause, of the failure to start.)

The OS is Windows 11 Enterprise 64-bit, build 22631. Launching Properties for WindowsSandbox.exe and going to Details shows the version is 10.0.22621.2506.

Comment: What are the values for the 2 keys within [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Containers\CmService\Policy]? Specifically DisableClone and DisableSnapshot

Comment: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Containers\CmService\Policy is empty. It has no subkeys or values.

Comment: Add those keys and set them to `1`

Comment: I did that. It didn't make a difference. Sorry, thought I commented about it yesterday but it looks like it didn't post. (Those are DWORD data entries, not keys, btw.) Ultimately I downloaded an ISO from Microsoft and did an in-place upgrade. Now the issue is gone, so that's good. Bummer for the curious that we'll never know what was actually wrong with it. Thanks for trying to help